# How to override the default name for in JAXB using a external binding file?

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, xjc

I have an element that looks something like this.

```
 <xsd:element name="container">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element ref="navmap"/>
        <xsd:element ref="keymap" />
        <xsd:element ref="container" />
        <xsd:element ref="ad" />
        <xsd:element ref="button" />
        <xsd:element ref="checkbox" />        
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

Here is the default code that gets created for this element.

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "navmap", type = Navmap.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "keymap", type = Keymap.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "container", type = Container.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "ad", type = Ad.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "button", type = Button.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "checkbox", type = Checkbox.class),
})
protected List<Object> navmapOrKeymapOrContainer;
```

My question is **What do I need to put in my** `.xjb` **bindings file to change the default generated name from** `navmapOrKeymapOrContainer` **to something else like** `children`**?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:property name="Shapes"/>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Rectangle" type="Rectangle"/>
    <xs:element name="Square" type="Square"/>
    <xs:element name="Circle" type="Circle"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Adapt this in your binding file and it will do. See [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/12/10/jaxb.html?page=2) for reference.

Listing 11 tells the secret:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
  jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="po4.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
  <jxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:superClass name="com.syh.
    <xjc:serializable uid="12343"/>
  </jxb:globalBindings>
  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Widgets']//xs:complexType//xs:choice">
      <jxb:property name="Shapes"/>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I can't modify the `.xsd` files they come from a vendor and I am not in control of them, I don't want to have to merge changes every time something changes on their end when I regenerate the bindings.

Comment: That's why I copied the listing 11. This snippet goes in your.binding file.