# How to override default name in JAXB using external binding?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, mapping

I am trying to use JAXB to convert xsd schema to java classes. Unfortunately I do have an issue. The xsd which casues problem is:

```
<xs:complexType name="AdditionalDataType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="AvailabilityStatus" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AvailabilityStatus" maxOccurs="999">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attributeGroup ref="IdentifierGrp"/>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The error I get is

```
[ERROR] \target\generated-sources\AdditionalDataType.java:[1012,22] AdditionalDataType.AvailabilityStatus is already defined in AdditionalDataType
```

I found this [How to override the default name for in JAXB using a external binding file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957568/how-to-override-the-default-name-for-in-jaxb-using-a-external-binding-file)
but when I tried to solve it with the following bindings:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AdditionalDataType']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='AvailabilityStatus']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='AvailabilityStatus']">
  <jxb:property name="AvailabilityStatusSA"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

it didn't help, it didn't change anything.

Can someone please help ?

@Ekrem 
I cannot modify the xml, I would do it but I cannot. I need to have AdditionalDataType which has a List of AvailabilityStatus
I dont care if the inner AvailabilityStatus (the one I am trying to map to AvailabilityStatusSA) will be an inner class or not.

Comment: why do you use same class name twice? can you please provide pseudo java class hierarchy that you want to produce with jaxb?

Comment: please see my update above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change
`<jxb:property name="AvailabilityStatusSA"/>` to `<jxb:class name="AvailabilityStatusSA"/>` and your binding node path should end with complexType ->`<jxb:bindings node=...[@name='AvailabilityStatus']xs:complexType"`

so your external binding file should look like this:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='AdditionalDataType']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='AvailabilityStatus']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='AvailabilityStatus']//xs:complexType">
  <jxb:class name="AvailabilityStatusSA"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```